# How can I preserve Winged Beans until my next batch matures?

Tags: freezing, beans

I am very proud that I have managed to grow a healthy crop of Winged Beans ( Psophocarpus tetragonolobus) in my small backyard garden. And the crop is quite reasonable. I was wondering if anyone had tips on how the beans could be stored. I am tempted to flash freeze them in sealed vacuumed bags.

Edit: These will be beans that I want to reserve for cooking... The beans that I am retaining for planting need to remain on the stake till the pods completely mature and dry.

Edit #2: Recipe added here for clarity, the beans are cooked and consumed pods and all.

#### Stir-Fried Winged Beans (Kacang Botol) with Tomato and Garlic

- 1/4 cup vegetable oil
- 6 cloves garlic, thinly sliced
- dried red chiles, to taste
- 1 pound winged beans (kacang botol), cut into bite-sized lengths
- 1/2 teaspoon salt
- 1 large tomato, diced
- 1 tablespoon soy sauce (gluten-free if needed)
- 1 teaspoon toasted sesame oil

Heat a wok or your largest skillet over maximum heat. Add the oil, and when it is shimering, add the garlic and chilis. Stir-fry for ten seconds, without burning, and immediately add the winged beans and salt.
Stir-fry for about 30 seconds, until the beans brighten in color.
Add the tomatoes and stir-fry about 30 more seconds, until the tomatoes just slightly begin to break down and form a sauce. Remove from heat.
Stir in the soy sauce and toasted sesame oil. Taste and adjust seasoning and serve immediately.

Comment: Are you asking how to preserve beans which you want to cook, or beans which you want to plant?

Comment: thank you for the edit, I was already thinking that I may have to migrate your question to Gardening.stackexchange.

Comment: So I haven't grown beans, but aren't you supposed to let beans (other than green beans, peas and snow peas) dry on the vine whether to eat or to grow?

Comment: I am going to post this question in gardening as well

Comment: @Escoce black-eyed peas are regularly picked fresh.